# Node-sass version issues with node and npm GitLab

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, package.json, node-sass

My `.yml` file in gitlab looks like this

```
stages:
  - prepare_build
  - save_build
  - deployment
image: node:latest
cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/
prepare_build:
  stage: prepare_build
  script:
  - npm install
  - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build
```

Below is my `package.json` file with `node-sass` and `sass-loader`

```
"node-sass": "^4.14.1",
"sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
```

My local Machine, build is success and it has node and npm versions

```
node : 14.5.0
npm : 6.14.8
```

Below is my GitLab build error

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /builds/../../node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /builds./../.././node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
```

what version combinations i have to update in my `package.json`? TIA

Comment: Yes you have to put version combinations in package.json

Comment: @GopalJoshi what are the combinations for latest node?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify the node image, the default is the latest which is not compatible with the version of node-sass you are using, try to specify in the build job the version of the node image:

```
prepare_build:
  image: node: 10.15.3
  ...
```